# Infiniteness of the pairs of sequences with a given conditions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, integer-sequences

Let
$$\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
Let
$$a_1(n)=\left\lfloor n\varphi \right\rfloor, a_2(n)=n+a_1(n)$$
Let $\operatorname{tr}(n)$ be [A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814), i.e., the number of trailing zeros in the binary representation of $n$. Here
$$\operatorname{tr}(2n+1)=0, \operatorname{tr}(2n)=\operatorname{tr}(n)+1$$

Let $b_1(n)$ and $b_2(n)$ be a pair of infinite complementary sequences (that is, each natural number occurs exactly once in one of the sequences) such that

- $b_1(1) = 1$ and $b_1(n)-b_1(n-m)$ belongs to $\left\lbrace a_2(m), a_2(m)+1 \right\rbrace$ for any $n>m>0$.
- $b_2(1) = 2$ and $b_2(n)-b_2(n-m)$ belongs to $\left\lbrace a_1(m), a_1(m)+1 \right\rbrace$ for any $n>m>0$.
- if $T(n,k)$ is infinite array such that $T(n,1)=b_1(n)$, $T(n,2)=b_2(b_1(n))$ and $T(n,k)=T(n,k-1)+T(n,k-2)$ for $k>2$, then each natural number occurs exactly once in this infinite array.
- if $c(n)=T(c(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^{\operatorname{tr}(n)+1}}\right\rfloor+1),\operatorname{tr}(n)+1)$ for $n>1$ with $c(1)=1$ and $d(n)=[n=b_1(k)]2d(k)+[n=b_2(k)]\cdot(2d(k)+1)$ for $n>1$ with $d(1)=0$, then $c(n)$ is a permutation of natural numbers and $d(n)$ is a permutation of nonnegative integers such that $d(c(n))=n-1$.

Examples of such sequences:

- $b_1(n)$ is [A007064](https://oeis.org/A007064), $b_2(n)$ is [A007067](https://oeis.org/A007067), $T(n,k)$ is [A035506](https://oeis.org/A035506), $d(n)$ is [A200714](https://oeis.org/A200714)
- $b_1(n)$ is [A007066](https://oeis.org/A007066), $b_2(n)$ is [A026355](https://oeis.org/A026355), $T(n,k)$ is [A126714](https://oeis.org/A126714), $d(n)$ is [A358654](https://oeis.org/A358654)
- $b_1(n)$ is [A003622](https://oeis.org/A003622), $b_2(n)$ is [A022342](https://oeis.org/A022342), $T(n,k)$ is [A035513](https://oeis.org/A035513), $d(n)$ is not in the OEIS

I conjecture that there are infinitely many pairs of sequences $b_1(n)$ and $b_2(n)$ with properties given above such that conditions for $T(n,k)$, $c(n)$ and $d(n)$ holds.

Is there a way to prove it?